# Using an enum from objective-c in swift class

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums

I have an enum in objective-c

```
typedef enum {
status1,
status2,
} BattStatus;
@property (nonatomic) BattStatus batStatus;
```

To use it in swift, I'm doing:

```
switch (MySingleton.sharedInstance().batStatus){
    case status1: break
    case status2: break
    default: break
}
```

It gives me error: `BattStatus does not conforms to protocol 'IntervalType'`. On line `case status1: break`

I cannot edit the first objective-c Singleton class yet. Just have to use it for now.

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C `enum` declarations are only imported as Swift `enum`s if the `NS_ENUM` macro is used. You'll need to use the `value` property on any `BattStatus` instance to access its value for comparison.

You can read more here: [C-Style "typedef enum" in Swift](http://natecook.com/blog/2014/07/c-style-typedef-enums-in-swift/)

Comment: thankfully, got to edit the obj-c singleton, so I Didn't get to test it,  but did you mean I'd have to do: `status1.value` ?

Comment: Both `status1.value` and `...batStatus.value`. The instances themselves aren't comparable.